# How can i render the side, only on a click and not with the React Hook useState?

Tags: reactjs

how can I trigger an onClick event and pass constants to a function without the use of the useState function?
Currently, as soon as I change something either in the text field or in the selection box, it is rendered again. So I just want to save the values ​​of the two elements and only transfer them to a function when I click on them

```
export default function ComboBox({ auswaehlen }) {
const [vorgesetzter, setVorgesetzter] = React.useState("");
const [org, setOrg] = React.useState("");

function handleChangeInput(e) {
 setVorgesetzter(e.target.innerText);
}

function handleChangeInputText(e) {
  setOrg(e.target.value);
}

return (
 <>
  <Row className="justify-content-center">
    <TextField
      id="standard-basic"
      label="ORG"
      value={org}
      onChange={handleChangeInputText}
    />
  </Row>
  <Row className="justify-content-center" style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      onChange={handleChangeInput}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Vorgesetzter"
          variant="outlined"
          value={vorgesetzter}
        />
      )}
    />
  </Row>
  <Row className="justify-content-center" style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      onClick={auswaehlen(org, vorgesetzter)}
    >
      übernehmen
    </Button>
  </Row>
</>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you just need to change this:

```js
onClick={auswaehlen(org, vorgesetzter)}
```

To this:

```js
onClick={() => auswaehlen(org, vorgesetzter)}
```

To invoke callback on click.

Otherwise it's invoked immediately when seen by compiler which is no good.